# want to match the column value with other column value in a same mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

[image: this is by table stucture..]

[image: this is my meny tree]

the image of menu tree is actuly the static name but now here i want that name fetch from my database table. i know how to select record from table like .. `select * from table_name where parent=0` ... and for selecting child `select * from table_name where parent>0`... i can understand how to implement it
but the problem is that now i want to run th

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from table_name where parent>=0
```

Comment: i know how to query i was asking logic behind it

Comment: the logic? like what it means? it would be select all from table_name where parent is greater than or equal to 0.... is that what you were asking?

Comment: i was asking how to implement the tree wise menu checkbox by fetching data from database